# Committing uncommited changes to another branch

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using sourcetree and only have master branch cloned locally. So I have been doing all my changes on master branch, and finally I have a lot of uncommited changes here on my local machine.

But right now I decided not to push them to master branch, but rather to develop branch - pretty old branch in my project. It exists on the origin, but not locally.

How can I first merge master to develop, so that they're the same, and then commit and push my changes to develop branch, leaving master untouched?

I've been thinking about:

```
git checkout origin/develop;
git merge master;
```

Ok, that would solve the first problem I think, but then my local changes would not be seen - source tree treats them as master changes I believe.

I am asking for this because I don't want to mess up anything in this project.

So - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Before `git checkout` and `git merge`, run

```
git stash
```

to save your uncommitted changes to the Git stash and remove them from your working tree. Then, after you've merged, run

```
git stash apply
git stash drop
```

to apply those changes you've stashed to your working tree (now on the `develop` branch) and remove the changes from the stash. You could instead run `git stash pop`, which combines `apply` and `drop`, but that has some tricky behavior (when hitting conflicts and such) that makes it better to usually just run `apply` and `drop` separately.